# SSAS 2008 R2 - Datasource with an DNS Alias not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dns, connection-string, ssas

I have an SQL Server with SQL Server Engine and SQL Server Analysis Services (2008 R2). The physical name of the server is SQ21. For beeing flexible we created a dns alias (Host A) which points to this server (respectively the IP Adress of the Server).
This works fine in nearly all scenarios

- Sql server management studio
- Deplyoing of SAAs Projects (Deployment Server)

We have one problem. If we want process the saas database i get an error:
"Error in relational Module. With the Datasource with ID could not be established a connecton"(attention, this is a tranlsation made by me from german, so the exact term could be slightly different)

As soon as I change the Datasource-Server Property back to the physical server it works.

What could be the problem? Kerberos? Or could it be that the both servers (sql server engine and saas) are on the same server?

Comment: have you flushed the dns cache? ipconfig /flushdns  Might well be as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and was able to find a fix.  You have to disable strict name checking on the server and add an entry to the BackConnectionHostNames list in the registry that matches the alias you want to use. See workaround method #1 of [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983444) for details on doing both (don't worry that the article is for SharePoint; the procedure applies to any app that uses loopback checking for authentication, which includes SSAS 2005/2008).  You may also need an SPN that matches your alias, so if it doesn't work after making the registry changes (and rebooting), try adding the SPN also.

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine have more than one IP address?  If so, it could be that MSSQL is not listening on the address to which the DNS host name resolves.

It could also be that the DNS entry has not propagated yet, or for some other reason your server is not resolving the host name to the correct IP address.  From a command prompt on the SQL Server machine, type

```
nslookup host.domain.com.
```

(use the DNS host name in place of host.domain.com, of course, and the "." at the end is important).  You should get something like this:

```
Server:  resolver.for.yourserver.com
Address:  12.34.56.78

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    host.domain.com
Address:  98.76.54.32
```

If that last address is not bound to the SQL Server or you don't get an answer, that's the issue.

Comment: The nslookup is correct as expected. It is also possible to connect to the sql-server in sql management studio with the dns alias. The problem is only in the Analysis Services Datasource. It is also possible to connect to the cube in analysis services from excel with the dns alias.